# Whats the equivalent of atom_to_term/3 across Prolog systems?

Tags: prolog

I find that SWI-Prolog offers:

> **atom_to_term(+Atom, -Term, -Bindings)**
> Use Atom as input to read_term/2 using the option variable_names
> and return the read term in Term and the variable bindings in Bindings.
> https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom_to_term/3

But I am having a hard time, figuring out what other Prolog systems
offer in this respect . Maybe some people did already obtain solutions,
that they might want to share?

Example what it does:

```
?- atom_to_term('X + Y', T, N).
T = _A+_B,
N = ['X'=_A, 'Y'=_B].
```

Answer (score 2):

Both [SWI](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_string/3) and [ECLiPSe](https://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/termmanip/term_string-3.html) support `term_string/3` and `atom_string/2`, with which you can write

```
atom_to_term(A, T, N) :-
    atom_string(A, S),
    term_string(T, S, [variable_names(N)]).
```

To make it quietly fail for malformed strings (syntax errors), use

```
atom_to_term(A, T, N) :-
    atom_string(A, S),
    term_string(T, S, [variable_names(N), syntax_errors(quiet)]).
```

Other error handling options are `fail` (print syntax error message and fail) and `error` (throw error/2 term).

Comment: How do I use it with error handling. Looks that it doesn't throw error and directly writes on the console: catch(term_string(Y, "x0 - x1 * x2 =:= x3 * x4 =:= x5 ** x6 - :- x7 , x8 - x9.", []), error(E,_), true).
string contains unexpected characters in term_string(Y, "x0 - x1 * x2 =:= x3 * x4 =:= x5 ** x6 - :- x7 , x8 - x9.")
Abort

Comment: I also don't understand what the "unexpected characters " should be.

Comment: @Ruben see my edit.

Comment: Ok, I see. Interesting... Will try.

Answer (score 1):

Logtalk, which runs on all those backend Prolog systems and several more, provides a portable [`term_io`](https://logtalk.org/manuals/libraries/term_io.html) library that implements reading/writing terms from/to atoms, chars (lists of characters), and codes (lists of character codes). For example using GNU Prolog:

```
$ gplgt
...
| ?- {term_io(loader)}.
...
% (0 warnings)

(202 ms) yes
| ?- term_io::read_term_from_atom('X + Y', Term, [variable_names(Vars)]).

Term = A+B
Vars = ['X'=A,'Y'=B]

yes
```

A period at the end of the atom is optional:

```
| ?- term_io::read_term_from_atom('a(X, Y).', Term, [variable_names(Vars)]).

Term = a(A,B)
Vars = ['X'=A,'Y'=B]

(1 ms) yes
```

Comment: Doesn't work as is in the browser for Tau Prolog. temporary_file/1 will probably bump into os:pid(PID). Possibly designed for the console only? Although I learned today that Tau Prolog has also files in the browser, but I don't know where they are stored?

Comment: True, Logtalk supports Tau Prolog in a shell, not in a browser. It *can* run also in a browser but that requires *embedding* (a script is available for it). Still, the OS/file system access limitation when running in a browser will prevent some libraries/tools from running even if embedded.

Comment: The semantics from term_io and GNU Prolog respectively SWI-Prolog natively is different. The laters require a terminating period in the atom. Does this prevent term_io to use GNU Prolog respectively SWI-Prolog natively and always use a termporary file?

Comment: From the linked API documentation: "A period at the end of the atom is optional."

Comment: Seems not to work for me, because I get `atom_to_term(' ', T, _).
T = end_of_file.`, but then I would get `read_term_from_atom(' ', T, []).
ERROR: Syntax error: Unexpected end of clause.` Because Logtalk would turn it into `read_term/2` from `' .'`. Also my bootstrapping solution for GNU Prolog is slightly wrong.

Comment: In "From the linked API documentation" I meant the **Logtalk** documentation, not the GNU Prolog documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I already found for GNU Prolog, that this could work:

```
atom_to_term(A, T, N) :-
   atom_concat(A, ' .', B),
   read_term_from_atom(B, T, [variable_names(N)]).
```

The example passes:

```
?- atom_to_term('X + Y', T, N).
N = ['X'=A,'Y'=B]
T = A+B
```

But what about Tau Prolog (Browser), Scryer Prolog, SICStus Prolog, ECLiPSe Prolog etc..?